# SQLiteConstraintException error code 19

Tags: android, sqlite

I' trying to insert some values in my database like here:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(ID, adv.getId());
        cv.put(NAME, adv.getName());
        cv.put(COUNTRY, country);

        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> E/SQLiteDatabase(19920): Error inserting id=14024
>   name=Banorte Generali Country=Mexico 
>   E/SQLiteDatabase(19920):
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: TableName.Countrytext
>   may not be NULL (code 19)

Here is the code of the creation of the database:

```
db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + ID
                + " integer primary key not null,"
                + NAME + " text, " + COUNTRY + 
                            " text not null"
                + ");");
```

What could I be doing wrong? I checked if the insert values are null but they arent, I checked for duplicates, bur the table is empty, any suggestions?

Comment: Did you check if its empty string after .trim()?

Comment: yup, I checked it on the debug and the input is not null

Comment: empty string and null is different.

Comment: yes still, the string is not either empty or null, in the log I posted it shows that it is actually trying to insert a value (in this example, Mexico) but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Could this  `cv.put(COUNTRY, country)` be `cv.put(COUNTRY, adv.getCountry())`

Comment: No, the country is a value I'm retrieving from the preferences, the adv is a custom object I created whose information I downloaded from a web service. What I'm trying to do is Depending on the country the user selects, show different types of advertisers the user has saved.

Comment: @CarlosT is your country value not null?

Comment: @Raghunandan nope its not, I checked it on the debug, is not null neither its empty. You can see that as well in the error log, where it shows it's actually trying to insert a value on country.

Comment: @CarlosT SQLiteConstraintException: TableName.Countrytext may not be NUL . this is what it says. so it's failing the query constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point in your code `COUNTRY` has the value `Countrytext` and the table has been created with that column.
Verify it by using `sqlite3`.

```
$ adb shell sqlite3 /data/data/your.package.name/databases/your.db .schema
```